# GIT : edit staged files in old commit but keep changes

Tags: git, commit, rebase, history, revert

I looked all over and couldn't find a solution to what I'm trying to do. Maybe I just missed it.

Say I have:

```
Commit A: 
- file 1
- file 2
- file 3
Commit B:
- file 4
Commit C:
- file 5
- file 6
HEAD: has files 1-6.
```

Is there a way to interactively go back to Commit A to uncommit file 2 and file 3, then replay the remaining commits?
So that I'm left with

```
Commit A: 
- file 1
Commit B:
- file 4
Commit C:
- file 5
- file 6
HEAD: has files 1-6, with file2 and file3 as unstaged.
```

**Incomplete solutions I found:**

```
- git reset --soft <commit A>
- make changes
- git commit
```

*but this leaves me without the remaining commits (B, C).*

```
- git rebase -i HEAD~n
- edit <commit>
- make changes
- git commit --amend
- git rebase --continue
```

*but changes here are on top of the committed files at that commit, and I don't want to undo the file changes, just uncommit/unstage them.*

```
- git revert -n <commit>
```

*but this undoes the changes.*

```
- git rebase drop <commit>
```

*but this drops the entire commit.*

I'm looking for the playback/--continue of rebase, but the editability of a soft reset. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
git rm -- file_2 file_3
git commit
```

This creates a new commit that removes the two files.  History is not altered.

To recover the two files in your working tree:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- file_2 file_3
git reset HEAD -- file_2 file_3
```

`git checkout` recovers the files and `git reset` removes them from the staging areas so that you won't commit them.

Alternatively, if you have not pushed these commits to a shared repository yet, and wish to change history, use `git rebase -i`

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n #n should be one more than the number of commits to change
#mark commit A to edit 
git reset -- file_2 file_3 # remove file_2 and file_3 from staging so they won't be committed
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

I believe this will leave file_1 and file_2 in your working tree.  If not, they can be recovered from your pre-rebase commit using git checkout as above.

Comment: Thanks, I see what this is doing. But in my case I had 50 files I wanted to uncommit. I want to 'travel back in time' to the see all the staged files for Commit A before they are committed to Commit A. Then I could selectively (re)commit only the files I want. 
Is that possible or asking too much of git?

Comment: That is possible.  Do `git reset -- .` to unstage everything then `git add -- <files to add>` followed by `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, @DavidSugar!    
I just tried `git rebase -i HEAD~n` -> edit commit.    
I get the message: 
```You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend 

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue``` and then ran 
`git reset -- .` but got no files unstaged. This is one of the things I tried before posting, but I'm not sure what I'm doing. Did I miss a step? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: sorry..that should be `git reset HEAD^ --.`  You want to reset the files to the previous commit--not the current one (which would result in no change to those files in the staging area).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! :) This created new staged files that undid the committed files, while retaining the original changes in unstaged files. I was able to `git commit --amend` and keep the changed files.